# Getting "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" error in Express

Tags: javascript, express

Screenshot of the error:

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Code of client side:

[image: Code of client side]

jwt attached api:

[image: jwt attached api]

Here's the jwt verifying function:

```
    const authHeader = req.headers?.authorization;
    if(!authHeader){
        return res.status(401).send({message: 'Unauthorized access'})
    }
    const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_TOKEN, (err, decoded)=>{
        if(err){
            return res.status(403).send({message: 'Forbidden access'})
        }
        console.log('decoded', decoded);
        req.decoded = decoded;
    })
    next();
}
```

Comment: Please add your code an error messages as text to your question (and pay attention to [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)). There are [many good reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557), why images of code are not a good idea.

Comment: Please supply the three images as text - images of text are not compatible with screen-readers, clipboards, or search engine robots. A code formatting device is available in the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error isn't related to jwt. This error happens if you try to do something with res object after response is sent. You can try to use return statement after or along with all your res.send() statements on server and that should resolve this error.